# Initialising fastclick with requirejs

Tags: cordova, requirejs, fastclick.js

I use requirejs with fastclick.
I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'trackingClick' of undefined
```

in Fastclick.js line 30 which does: `this.trackingClick = false;`

In config.js I run app.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
       fastclick:'fastclick'
    }    
)};
require(['app'], function (App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

In my `app.js` I do:

```
define(['fastclick'], function(fastclick){
    var app = { 
        initialize: function () {
            var attachFastClick = require('fastclick');
            attachFastClick(document.body);
        }
    }
    return app;
}
```

The browser starts fine and in the debugger the fastclick library is properly instantiated and resolved but still `this` in the Fastclick.js cannot be resolved.

I also tried `fastclick(document.body);` but it did not seem to have any effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Looking through the Fastclick code I found the following functions which works:
`Fastclick.attach`

So, instead of calling:

```
 var attachFastClick = require('fastclick');
        attachFastClick(document.body);
```

The following works:

```
 fastclick.attach(document.body);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my app, I simply use the code seen below to properly initialize my app with fastclick.  I removed all the other irrelevant lines of code to make my solution more clear

```
define([
    'fastclick',
], function(FastClick){
    var initialize = function(){
        new FastClick(document.body);
    }
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes like dsheene said the FastClick library will return `FastClick.attach` for Browserify or another CommonJS-style only. For the AMD style FastClick will return the full `FastClick` object.

From the FastClick source:

```
if (typeof define !== 'undefined' && define.amd) {
  // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
  define(function() {
    'use strict';
    return FastClick;
  });
}
```

in your app.js file you want to.

```
define(['fastclick'], function(fastclick){
  var app = { 
    initialize: function () {
      var FastClick = require('fastclick');
      FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }
  }
  return app;
}
```